# Setting JS content by another JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to do some kind of this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0].innerHTML = 'alert(123);';
</script>
```

so then `alert` would be executed?

(I just want to mock of my browser)

Comment: You're looking for `eval()`.  This is a giant security hole; don't do it.

Comment: Also, what's the reason you can't just call `alert(123);` directly, if you want it to execute immediately?

Comment: if you want to mock for rapid development, try jsfiddle.net